# cmake: how to define target without linking (compilation only)

Tags: cmake

Is there any simple way to create a target where object files aren't linked?
I need additional target only for tests if everything compiles for ARM.
I don't want to create any executable (it would not link anyway), because my project will be finally a part of something much bigger, which has its own old stable make-based build system.

So I just need to compile sources. All tests are done with other, PC target compiled with gcc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use an [object library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#object-libraries):

```
add_library(dummy OBJECT <source files>)
```

See also:

- [add_library => object-libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries)
- [Official tutorial](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/Object-Library).