# how to construct source_target in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

If use Gn we can declare source target use [source_set](https://gn.googlesource.com/gn/+/HEAD/docs/reference.md#func_source_set), and source_set is explained as follow:

> A source set is a collection of sources that get compiled, but are not
> linked   to produce any kind of library. Instead, the resulting object
> files are   implicitly added to the linker line of all targets that
> depend on the source   set.
>
> In most cases, a source set will behave like a static library,
> except no   actual library file will be produced. This will make the
> build go a little   faster by skipping creation of a large static
> library, while maintaining the   organizational benefits of focused
> build targets.
>
> The main difference between a source set and a static library is
> around   handling of exported symbols. Most linkers assume declaring a
> function   exported means exported from the static library. The linker
> can then do dead   code elimination to delete code not reachable from
> exported functions.
>
> A source set will not do this code elimination since there is no
> link step.   This allows you to link many source sets into a shared
> library and have the   "exported symbol" notation indicate "export
> from the final shared library and   not from the intermediate
> targets." There is no way to express this concept   when linking
> multiple static libraries into a shared library.

My question is How to construct a source_set in cmake?

Comment: You are probably talking about OBJECT library. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634101/cmake-how-to-define-target-without-linking-compilation-only) for more details.